# jQuery Tabs - Implement Ajax load for specific tab(s)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a jQuery Tabs element that allows graphical separation of modules in a flat web application.  Currently a great deal of the data used by the application is static, which allows for client side caching, but future plans include more modules that will require more frequent updates.  So what I'd like to do is implement a way to have a specific tab click fire off an ajax query.

Currently, I have something like this:

```
<div id = "tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href = "#parentorg_tab">Parent Organizations</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#client_tab">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#county_tab">Counties</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#vendor_tab">Vendors</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

which is initialized via

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
  activate : function(event, ui){
    if (ui.newTab.attr("aria-controls") == "client_tab"){
      getClientOrgs();
    }
  }
});
```

Each tab contains an `aria-controls` attribute which corresponds to the href value of the unordered list of tabs.  Aside from checking for this attribute on each click, is there an alternative method?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a simple answer, but have you consider implementing an onClick event on each `<a>`?
I could fire a js method with an Ajax request or anything you need without having to write nested ifs on the activate function.